# How to rename all columns to middle separator in R?

Tags: r

I'm looking for an easy solution to rename my columns to only the middle separator. Here's some mock data.

```
dat <- data.frame(
  
  subject = paste("Subject", 1:10),
  CT_tib_all = round(rnorm(10, 0.25, 0.03), 2),
  CT_lum_all = round(rnorm(10, 0.25, 0.03), 2),
  CT_tho_all = round(rnorm(10, 0.25, 0.03), 2)
  
)
```

I'd like to go from this:

```
    subject CT_tib_all CT_lum_all CT_tho_all
1 Subject 1       0.25       0.27       0.26
2 Subject 2       0.24       0.19       0.21
```

To this:

```
    subject        tib        lum        tho
1 Subject 1       0.25       0.27       0.26
2 Subject 2       0.24       0.19       0.21
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be more elegant solutions, but try this:

```
colnames(dat)[-1] <- sapply(strsplit(colnames(dat[-1]), "_"), function(x) x[2])

#> dat
#      subject  tib  lum  tho
#1   Subject 1 0.17 0.21 0.20
#2   Subject 2 0.27 0.23 0.28
# ...
```

This ignores the first (`subject`) column and `sapply()` will find everything in between the underscores for the remaining columns.

Answer (score 1):

With the {tidyverse} you can use `dplyr::rename_with()` and supply a function that splits at the `_` and takes the 2nd element.

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat <- data.frame(
  subject = paste("Subject", 1:10),
  CT_tib_all = round(rnorm(10, 0.25, 0.03), 2),
  CT_lum_all = round(rnorm(10, 0.25, 0.03), 2),
  CT_tho_all = round(rnorm(10, 0.25, 0.03), 2)
)

# create renaming function
f <- function(x) {
  x %>% 
    str_split("_") %>% 
    map(~.x[2]) %>% 
    unlist()
}

# rename with function at specified positions
dat %>% 
  rename_with(f, -1)
#>       subject  tib  lum  tho
#> 1   Subject 1 0.28 0.25 0.23
#> 2   Subject 2 0.26 0.25 0.26
#> 3   Subject 3 0.28 0.29 0.25
#> 4   Subject 4 0.30 0.26 0.24
#> 5   Subject 5 0.22 0.24 0.23
#> 6   Subject 6 0.26 0.28 0.29
#> 7   Subject 7 0.26 0.22 0.26
#> 8   Subject 8 0.29 0.26 0.25
#> 9   Subject 9 0.24 0.32 0.26
#> 10 Subject 10 0.21 0.23 0.27
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Another option using `rename_with()` with `str_extract()` to extract the string between two "_" and rename columns accordingly excluding the first column.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

rename_with(dat, ~str_extract(.x, '(?<=_).*?(?=_)'), .cols = -1)
```

Also using `purrr:map()` as follows

```
library(purrr)

colnames(dat)[-1] <- map_chr(colnames(dat)[-1], ~strsplit(.x,'_')[[1]][2])
```